# Perl: How to join two columns of a text file, in which values of the first column should match in order with the values of the second column

Tags: perl, bioinformatics

I am a beginner with Perl programming. The problem I am working on right now is how to get the gene length from a text file. Text file contains the gene name (column 10), start site (column 6), end site (column 7). The length can be derived from the difference of column 6 and 7. But my problem is how to match the gene name (from column 10) with the corresponding difference derived from the difference of column 6 and column 7. Thank you very much!

```
open (IN, "Alu.txt");
open (OUT, ">Alu_subfamlength3.csv");

while ($a = <IN>) {
    @data = split (/\t/, $a);
    $list {$data[10]}++;
    $genelength {$data[7] - $data[6]};
}

foreach $sub (keys %list){
    $gene = join ($sub, $genelength);

    print "$gene\n";
}
close (IN);
close (OUT);
```

Comment: We'll need to see samples of your input data and the output you want from that input.

Comment: Also, I've just fixed the indentation of your code. You're very welcome, of course, but please consider doing yourself in the future. Good indentation is a massive help in understanding code, and when you're asking a large number of strangers to read and understand your code it's only polite to make it as easy for them as possible.

Comment: cross posted: https://www.biostars.org/p/390114/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about this as I haven't seen your data. But I think you're making this far harder than necessary. I think that everything you need for each gene is in a single line of the input file, so you can process the file a line at a time and not use any extra variables. Something like this:

```
open (IN, "Alu.txt");
open (OUT, ">Alu_subfamlength3.csv");

while ($a = <IN>) {
    @data = split (/\t/, $a);
    print "Gene: $data[10] / Length: ", $data[7] - $data[6], "\n";
}
```

But there are some improvements we can make. First, we'll stop using `$a` (which is a special variable and shouldn't be used in random code) and switch to `$_` instead. At the same time we'll add `use strict` and `use warnings` and ensure that all of our variables are declared.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open (IN, "Alu.txt");
open (OUT, ">Alu_subfamlength3.csv");

while (<IN>) { # This puts the line into $_
    my @data = split (/\t/); # split uses $_ by default
    print OUT "Gene: $data[10] / Length: ", $data[7] - $data[6], "\n";
}
```

Next we'll remove the unnecessary parentheses on the `split()` call and use a list slice to just get the values you want and store them in individual variables.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open (IN, "Alu.txt");
open (OUT, ">Alu_subfamlength3.csv");

while (<IN>) { # This puts the line into $_
    my ($start, $end, $gene) = (split /\t/)[6, 7, 10]; # split uses $_ by default
    print OUT "Gene: $gene / Length: ", $end - $start, "\n";
}
```

Next, we'll remove the explicit filenames. Instead, we'll read data from `STDIN` and write it to `STDOUT`. This is a common Unix/Linux approach called an *I/O filter*. It will make your program more flexible (and, as a bonus, easier to write).

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<>) { # Empty <> reads from STDIN
    my ($start, $end, $gene) = (split /\t/)[6, 7, 10];
    # print to STDOUT
    print "Gene: $gene / Length: ", $end - $start, "\n";
}
```

To use this program, we use an operating system feature called *I/O redirection*. If the program is called `filter_genes`, we would call it like this:

```
$ ./filter_genes < Alu.txt > Alu_subfamlength3.csv
```

And if the names of your files change in the future, you don't need to change your program, just the command line that calls it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your input data is tab delimited and you wanted an output csv file containing gene name and its corresponding gene length

**Expected Output**

```
genename1,12
genename2,20
genename3,8
```

Below is the code I made with those assumptions

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $input_file;
my $output_file;

my %hash_gene;

open ($input_file,  "<testdata.txt") or die "Can not open file [$input_file]";
open ($output_file, ">outdata.txt")  or die "Can not open file [$output_file]";

while (<$input_file>) {
    chomp;
    my @data = split (/\t/, $_);

    $hash_gene{$data[10]} = $data[7] - $data[6];
}

foreach my $sub (keys %hash_gene){
    print $output_file "$sub,$hash_gene{$sub}\n";
}   
close ($input_file);
close ($output_file);
```

**Notes**

- I modified the files names, change them as needed
- Array index is 0-based, I assume you considered that when you mentioned the column numbers (Such that the first column is Column 0)

Comment: This is very much helpful! Thank you very much. Yup, my input file is a tab delimited file, I just don't know yet how to program using Perl. I am really a newbie.